# Como copiar una columna de una tabla en mysql a una segunda tabla "Vacia"?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero copiar los datos de una columna de una tabla con datos , a otra que acabo de crear, solo necesito duplica la primary key para ponerla como foreign key en la segunda tabla, pero hacerlo manualmente va a ser muy tardado, si alguien sabe como hacer esto se lo agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues ya lo resolvi, se hace bastante facil con esta sentencia

```
INSERT INTO tabla_destino (campo1, campo2) SELECT tabla_origen.campo1, tabla_origen.campo2 FROM tabla_origen
```

Lo dejo por si en un futuro le sirve a alguien